# Python-Pygame os.system how to close MAIN file-Pygame screen

Tags: python, python-3.x, operating-system, pygame, python-3.4

I am making a game with Pygame that has some buttons, when touching a special button it's opening another .exe file. Im doing that with this way;

```
os.system("filename.exe")
```

But Pygame screen stays at background, I want to close that screen when the user click that button and open that .exe file. I tried this;

```
#codes
...
...
if action == "play":
    os.system("filename.exe")
    pygame.quit()
    quit()
```

Theorically it should be work, opened .exe file after then quit from Pygame. But this isn't working, .exe file opened succesfuly but Pygame screen still stays at the background and if I touch it, giving error ***Pygame stop working.***

> How can I fix this? When that special .exe file opened, close the
>   Pygame screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`os.system`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system) wait the program terminate; the next line `pygame.quit` will not executed until the termination of the process. Instead of `os.system`, you can use [`subprocess.Popen`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) which does not wait the program termination (or any other functionality that does not wait the process termination):

```
import subprocess

....


if action == "play":
    subprocess.Popen(["filename.exe"])
    pygame.quit()
    quit()
```

Comment: Well actually it does work if I run the game with IDLE(f5) but now another problem appears. When I try to run my game with double-click or using terminal(cmd) it's not opening that .exe file. Just closing the Pygame screen. Why ?

Comment: @grrr, Do you see any error message in the terminal? Maybe the current working directory does not contain the file. Please try specify the full path of the executable.

Comment: Unfortunately no, they are in the same directory I'm sure about that. Also I'am opening the terminal in that directory. No error message, nothing wrong except it doesn't open the .exe file. I am trying to understand why.

Comment: @grrr, Current working directory != the directory that contains the python script.

Comment: @grrr, Coudl you try with `shell=True`? `subprocess.Popen(["filename.exe"], shell=True)`

Comment: O my god my fault hahahahah. I am using _win32gui.ShowWindow(win,0)_ that hiding terminal, and my .exe file is working on terminal.. This is why it seems it doesn't opened. Thanks for answer&help.

Comment: @grrr, You're welcome. Nice to help you. Happy hacking.